# Pip crashes after installing beautifulSoup and updating pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

After i install beautiful soup and update pip, pip crashes when run anything related to it even a (pip --version)
this error appears anytime i want to use pip!! i tried to uninstall it to but ALSO IT DIDN'T WORK and gives me the same message

```
C:\Users>pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==22.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but it was okay when i installed beautifulSoup(btw it didn't work either)

```
 C: \Users>pip install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/d8/909C4089dbe4ade9f9705f143c9f13f065849a9d5e7d34c82Baefdd0a97c
beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl(128kB)
100% |################################| 133kB 1.6MB/s
Collecting soupsieve>1.2 (from beautifulsoup4)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/e3/4ad79882b926173a4a@df196@d6bce@8edfb637737ac5c3f3ba29022e25
/soupsieve-2.3.2.post1-py3-none-any.whl
red
(ed installine collected pactagest souysieve, beautifulsoups
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.11.1 soupsieve-2.3.2.post1
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the
*python -m pip install
--upgrade pip' command,
L Disd
C: \Users>python -m pip install - -upgrade pip
Edit
Collecting pip
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/2c/d9626f845e7b49a6225c6b09257861f24da78f45f23af2ddbdf852c99b8
/pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl(2.0MB)
100% ################################| 2.0MB 328kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 8.1.1
Uninstalling pip-8.1.1:
Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.1
Successfully installed pip-22.2.2
```

I need to do projects with beautifulsoup but I cann't and I don't know what to do I'm searching for a solution and still cann't figure it out.
**Note: I'm still a beginner so, any solution you can offer me please give it to me with steps and thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You somehow managed to install a version of pip for Python 3.6+, while your current Python install is Python 3.5.

However, instead of fixing the current install, I would instead suggest upgrading to the latest version of Python, given that Python 3.5 has been unsupported for over 2 years.

To do so, just uninstall the current installation, download and install Python 3.10 from https://www.python.org/downloads/, and reinstall any packages through pip.